# server side technology for business logic

Tags: deployment, server-side, business-logic

I want to develop a web application that will have registered users and will be registered as a twitter app (allowing users to give it permissions to view their timeline and post on their behalf). The sole function of the application will be to re-tweet tweets from users' timeline according to users' settings and desires.

I understand that the website for this app will use the common technologies like HTML, CSS and JS on the client-side. The server side (where the user defines what kind of tweets the application should retweet) will have to be coded in PHP/Python/Perl/... based on a DB MySQL/Postgre/...

What I don't understand, and would really appreciate your help with, is where the real "business logic" will be coded? For example, what technology should I use to code the function that will sit on my server: contacting Twitter server every 5 minutes, reading the timeline of every user I have, checking whether there are tweets worth retweeting (according to what the user has defined), and sending Tweeter the necessary commands to retweet the chosen tweets on behalf of my users.

All that will happen off-line for the user, and will be an on-going and cyclic process - but what technology should I use to code it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have heard about [this API for PHP](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth). It is actually the only one that I have heard of for PHP, though. I know that there are some good Python libraries out there, but I don't know about Perl.

I am actually working on a new API for C# (won't be a good fit for you, as you're clearly not using Windows Servers), and started building it while working on an enterprise web application that prompted several questions similar to your own.

Here is what you are going to have to do:

1. Before you start, you are going to have to get in touch with one of Twitter's data partners (I believe that you may contact Twitter for the reference)

   - The reason for this is that you are going to be requiring many more requests than you think
   - Twitter's time interval used for Twitter's recorded rate cap is 900 seconds (5 minutes)
   - With the general rate limit if you are querying a user's timeline only once every rate limit, you are limiting your number of visitors on your site to 300 at a time
   - Here's where it gets tricky - if every user makes one Tweet (meaning you send the Tweet - not rate limited - and then refresh the timeline - rate limited - so that they can see the updated tweet) you have now dropped your maximum number of active users at any given time to 150
   - Factor in the company's own timeline (-1 visitor), plus the number of visitors who leave their browsers open (now you need more logic, and you have to either kick them off or simply keep track of whose timeline you won't be refreshing), the number of users who make more than one tweet (-1 visitor for each Tweet), etc.
   - *Moral of the story*: contact one of their data partners and get yourself either unlimited requests, or at least a significant enough amount to accommodate your number of visitors/users (plus a bit of padding)
   - **If you adhere to this advise, skip steps 2 and 3, otherwise, skip step 4**
2. (Note: Steps 2 and 3 are only for rate-capped implementations) Using your desired language, make a service that runs on the server and makes the queries to Twitter

   - Based on the information that you gave, I suggest that you use Python to make this service
   - The service will run at all times and be on it's own clock to base the 5-minute intervals between the requests on
   - You will have to use a caching or a database system for storing the data
3. (Note: Steps 2 and 3 are only for rate-capped implementations) Add the necessary code to make a request to the service that you created for the data and perform these requests every 5 minutes

   - I suggest that the clock used for making these requests to the service be running a little bit behind the clock used for the service to account for instances of slow data transfer, etc.
   - You will also have to have to call some methods on the service for adding/removing users from the queue
4. (Note: Step 4 is only for unlimited request implementations) Forget about the service and simply include the request code directly in the page that the user is on.

   - The user's timeline will be updated based on when they visited the site or when their timeline was last refreshed (if a Tweet was made)
   - The only caveat to this implementation is that you will have to pay for the unlimited/larger data rate limit